# What is the difference between will be better and would be better?

Tags: differences

it will be better to add more photos in the website.
it would be better to add more photos in the website.

Is both statement are same?  if no please clarify me

Comment: It's all just speculation.

Comment: Use citations in your question, if you please.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. "It would be better to" is a suggestion for improvement or a criticism but "It will be better to" is an explanation of or a justification for a decision already taken.

However "it would be better to" seems to be much more common than "it will be better to" according to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+be+better+to%2Cwill+be+better+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20be%20better%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20better%20to%3B%2Cc0) and this matches my own experience.

A much more usual way of saying "it will be better to do X" is "it will be better *when we(or I, or you or they)* do X". In other words your sentences would become **"It will be better when we**(or I, or you, or they) **add more photos to the website**" and **"It would be better to add more photos to the website".**

The first indicates that there is the intention, and perhaps a plan, to add more photos, and that this will improve the experience. It would also explain why the experience of a website under development or at the prototype stage is less good than it should be.

The second indicates that the speaker, who may or may not be a member of the development team, feels that the website needs more photos to improve the experience but does not know of any plan to do that.

Comment: How is "The weather will be better tomorrow" a justification for a decision?

Comment: 'It will be better to stay inside until the rain has stopped' is often just a more strongly phrased piece of advice than 'It would be better to stay inside until the rain has stopped'.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not. I was saying that "It will be better _to_ was a justification for a decision as the OP asked. There are obviously many other uses of "It will be better".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I know what you mean, but I would say that it is more strongly phrased because the speaker has already decided to stay where inside. In other words that it is a statement of a decision already made whether or not the rest of the group agrees.

Comment: No. A person who says either 'It will be better to stay inside until the rain has stopped' **or** 'It would be better to stay inside until the rain has stopped' has already made a decision (of judgement). We don't know if they will act this out if everybody else ignores their advice (and the implications of staying inside alone might be different). But certainly 'will' is more forceful, probably meaning they are more likely to stay on their own than if they'd used 'would'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Correct.  "Would" suggests that the speaker has not completely made up his mind yet, but "will" indicates that he is unlikely to change his opinion (or the way he weighs conflicting factors).